# Css Drop down menu background image getting cut off

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with this. I'm in the process of building a website and I'm used to using background colors and this time I wanted to use this background image. It looks good up to this point But when I set the drop down menu itself to display:none;  (which is commented) it cuts off the drop menu background. I've tried to mess around with paddings settings But I couldn't get a satisfacory result. I even tried to set up borders so that I could see what the paddings and margins are at... but they never would show up.  I went ahead and uploaded what I have to lizzyengagement.com   any help would be greatly appreciated.
below is my HTML/CSS
HTML:__________________________________________________________________

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wedCss.css"/>
<center><div class="topper">
<img src="Winter_Snowy_Black_Tree_PNG_Picture.png"class="top1" ><img src="imageedit_11_6486922729.gif" class="top2"width="400"><img src="Winter_Snowy_Black_Tree_PNG_Picture.png" class="top3" >
</div></center>
<center>
<div id='canvas' height=200 width=600>
<nav id='primary_nav_wrap'>
<ul>
 <li class='current-menu-item'><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='wedParty.html'>Wedding Party</a>
    <ul>
      <li class='dir'><a href='groomsmen.html'>Groomsmen</a></li>
      <li><a href='bridesmaids.html'>Bridesmaids</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href='registries.html'>Wedding Registry's</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=''>Walmart</a></li>
      <li><a href=''>Target</a></li>
      <li><a href=''>Bed Bath and Beyond</a></li>
      <li><a href=''>Best Buy</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='rsvp.php'>RSVP NOW!</a>
  <ul>
      <li><a href='rsvp.php'>Respond to wedding invitation</a></li>
      <li><a href='hotelSuggestions.html'>Reserve your Hotel today </a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href='contactUs.html'>Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</header>
<body>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

</body>
<footer>
.
</footer>
</html>
```

CSS_______________________________________________________________________

```
body
{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(180, 139, 170), rgb(52, 10, 55) ); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(180, 139, 170), rgb(52, 10, 55) ); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(180, 139, 170), rgb(52, 10, 55) ); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(180, 139, 170), rgb(52, 10, 55) ); /* Standard syntax */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;

  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.topper
{
width:%100;


}
.top1
{
 margin-left:fixed;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20%;
}
.top2
{
 margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;  
}
.top3
{
 margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: fixed;
    width: 20%;  
}
#primary_nav_wrap
{
width:100%;

 background-image: url('link_back.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  background-position:center;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul
{

    position:relative;



}
#primary_nav_wrap ul  a
{

color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
position:relative;
    float:center;
    margin-left:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#aaa
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
/*
display:none;
*/ 
}
```

Comment: Remember that the background image will only occupy the space of the element. Please provide some of the code so we can better help you

Comment: I just added the code

Comment: so i have the very base tag with Primary nav wrap with its back ground shouldnt it be seen through all of it?

Comment: I figured it out  thanks for the hint Ibu!